# How do I set up WINE on Ubuntu so that I can play my Windows games on it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

Other than the default install of WINE from the Ubuntu repo, is there anything else I should do in order to run a game? 
Should I use something like winetricks or is that unnecessary? I really just want to run some 3D and 2D games with the minimum amount of fuss.

Comment: Could you give an example of which games you are trying to play?

Comment: winetricks is a realy helpfull tool you should consider installing since i dont think you want to search and recompile all windows files your self. And for wine there is a good tutorial on the ubuntu forum https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Wine/

Comment: @Gerret nothing too fancy or new, some old stuff like Black and White, Civ3, Alpha Centauri, (new) Shadowrun, some emulators that didn't get Linux ports or open source.

Comment: @warsong Btw there are some Linux-Distributionens where wine is already installed and good to go (Manjaro also has steam by default) gl and hf

Comment: I highly recommend using PlayOnLinux, which is a frontend for WINE/WINEtricks. It will install games for you with the proper settings and versions of WINE automagically.

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful to use a tool like [Lutris](https://lutris.net/) or [Play on Linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) or [Play on MAC](https://www.playonmac.com/en/) to facilitate running applications under Wine.  Both offer online resources that people have put together to simplify or automate fulfilling requirements for getting games to work.

For example, one might take a look at [Install Lutris On Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux](https://www.playonmac.com/en/)

Lutris' [list of games](https://linuxconfig.org/install-lutris-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) with install scripts is huge and the others similarly support many different install scenarios.